# Update quantity in database

Tags: php, mysql

My MySQL table looks as follows:

> **Item_Id**      **Item_Name**     **quantity**
>  1                 
>   HPWT 20         20

The quantity field is an integer.

Now, if I bought this "HPWT 20" item again with quantity "5" , I want my table affected as follows:

> **Item_Id**      **Item_Name**     **quantity**
>  1                  HPWT 20         25

What I always do is: first I select the previous quantity from the database, then add new quantity to it, then update the quantity with new one at the desired **Item_Id**.

Is there another (direct) way to Update the quantity?

Comment: Just so you know, questions are generally written only with a minimum of emboldening/quoting etc - excessive formatting can make text more difficult to read. If you want to render tabular data, paste in the data and use the code button - it saves the need for adding in the `&nbsp;` to make stuff line up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can execute a UPDATE directly:

```
UPDATE table SET quantity = quantity + 5 WHERE Item_id = <x>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check:
[Increment value in mysql update query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259155/increment-value-in-mysql-update-query)
Or:
http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/2139/mysql_increment_an_exisitng_value/

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE t1 SET quantity = quantity + 5 WHERE item_id = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is :

```
UPDATE mytable 
  SET quantity = quantity + 5
  WHERE Item_Id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This can simply be achieved like this:

```
UPDATE
    item
SET
    quantity = quantity + 5
WHERE
    item_id = 1
```