# How to run a automated query daily

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named "trans" with this structure

```
#   Name    Type    Collation   Attributes  Null    Default Extra   Action
 1  user_id int(11)         No  None    Change Change    Drop Drop   Browse distinct values Browse distinct values   Primary Primary     Unique Unique   Index Index    Spatial Spatial Show more actions More
 2  amount  decimal(16,8)   No  None     Change Change   Drop Drop   Browse distinct values Browse distinct values   Primary Primary     Unique Unique   Index Index    Spatial Spatial Show more actions More
 3  aff int(11)             No  0        Change Change   Drop Drop   Browse distinct values Browse distinct values   Primary Primary     Unique Unique   Index Index    Spatial Spatial Show more actions More
 4  jackpot int(11)         No  0        Change Change   Drop Drop   Browse distinct values Browse distinct values   Primary Primary     Unique Unique   Index Index    Spatial Spatial Show more actions More
 5  paidout int(11)         No  0        Change Change   Drop Drop   Browse distinct values Browse distinct values   Primary Primary     Unique Unique   Index Index    Spatial Spatial Show more actions More
 6  type    int(11)         No  0        Change Change   Drop Drop   Browse distinct values Browse distinct values   Primary Primary     Unique Unique   Index Index    Spatial Spatial Show more actions More
 7  created timestamp       No  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP        Change Change   Drop Drop   Browse distinct values Browse distinct values   Primary Primary     Unique Unique   Index Index    Spatial Spatial Show more actions More
```

This table keep growing millions of rows and every few days a have to collapse the table  doing  this query:

```
SELECT user_id,paidout,sum(amount) as amount FROM trans GROUP BY user_id,paidout
```

then i export the result of this query to my computer in sql format

then i empty the "trans" table and then i import to "trans" the sql file i exported from that query above.

My question is , if there is any way to make this process run automated daily?

Comment: Do you really need to do it with MySQL **and** Microsoft SQL Server or you've slipped a wrong tag?

Comment: Yes. Read about crontab and bash scripts.

Comment: If it's MySQL, you can use the [Event scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/events.html), if it's MS sql server, use the sql server agent.

Comment: why don't you simply update the fields instead of adding a complete new row and grouping it after?

Comment: @chresse i would update if you can suggest me the exact query , but i could not find another way to do this.

Comment: `UPDATE trans SET amount = amount + <amountToAdd> WHERE user_id = <userId>`

Comment: @chresse #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '<amountToAdd> WHERE user_id = <userId>' at line 1

Comment: @user38935 you have to adjust the command with the values you need. have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259155/increment-value-in-mysql-update-query to see how values are incremented by `UPDATE`