# How to increase the value of column by 1 in mysql or phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to increment a field value by (+1) in every row of mysql table.

How to do that using mysql or phpmyadmin?

Comment: Just once or do you want to increment more than once?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Increment value in mysql update query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259155/increment-value-in-mysql-update-query)

Answer (score 6):

```
update my_table set my_field = my_field+1
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use an update  eg:

```
update my_table  
set my_column  = my_column +1
```